# Pagination using oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

```
I have problem in Oracle ADF pagination 
Bean code is:     
    private UIXIterator purVO1Iterator;
private int rowsPerPage = 20;
public void previousActionListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
this.getPurVO1Iterator().setFirst(this.getPurVO1Iterator().getFirst() -
                                  rowsPerPage);
}

public void nextActionListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
this.getPurVO1Iterator().setFirst(this.getPurVO1Iterator().getFirst() +
                                  rowsPerPage);
```

}
   jsp code is:

```
 <af:iterator id="i11" var="row" 
          value="#{bindings.purVO1.collectionModel}"
          binding="#{backingBeanScope.Purchage.purVO1Iterator}"
          rows="#{backingBeanScope.Purchage.rowsPerPage}">
```

..............

Here problem is it taking  long time when we click next button . Is there any better solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the range setting of the executable that is used by your iterator Purchage. Also you should check the settings on the VO tuning section for your query.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to go to your pageDef where this iterator tree is defined and set the rangeSize on the iterator there. Also, you might want to check in the VO definition. Setting it on the iterator would not override the setting done on the VO.